# How do I need to make a list of numbers within the range of the sum?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, summation

Given

```
(matX = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}});
(matZ = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Exp[ 2 Pi I/3], 0}, {0, 0, Exp[ 4 Pi I/3]}});
w = Exp[I 2 Pi /3];
```

Then I set `m=0` as the initiate,next

```
Do[
   Print k = 
   1/Sqrt[9] Sum[
               (w^cc MatrixPower[matX, i]. MatrixPower[matZ, j]),
               {i,0,2},
               {j,0,2}];

 Print[m]; 
 m++
 Print[cc], {cc, 0, 2}, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}]
```

However, nothing is coming out as the output. I want it to come out as
002022201 represent the power of w for each summation of mat X and mat Z. It has to be nine as it represents nine matrices(since it is 3x3 matrices) Why it didn't come out? Did I miss a command?

Comment: If I add missing [ and ] after your first Print, like this: Do[Print[k=1/Sqrt[9] Sum[w^cc MatrixPower[matX, i].MatrixPower[matZ, j], {i,0,2}, {j,0,2}]]; Print[m]; m++; Print[cc], {cc,0,2}, {i,0,2}, {j,0,2}] then it prints just fine for me. Perhaps those [ and ] were lost in the posting process, perhaps not. Related subject, IF you look carefully at the subtle controls available to you when posting you may find how it is possible to have code formatted differently than plain text. That can help readability and keep some of the publishing from eating bits of your code.

Comment: @Bill I overlook about [and] when I wrote the command here but in mathematica,that is not the case. Did you really get the output as numbers which represent the power of w?

Comment: what's `m`....?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do, but something like this -- define a function to carry out the calculation in the sum:

```
sumcc[cc_] := 1/Sqrt[9] Sum[(w^cc MatrixPower[matX, i].MatrixPower[matZ, j]), 
                            {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}] // N // Chop
```

(I added the `N` and `Chop` to remove the small imaginary roundoff calculations). Now you can evaluate the terms by

```
sumcc[0]
sumcc[1]
```

etc. To calculate them all at once

```
sumcc[#]&/@Range[0,2]
```

or add them up

```
Total[sumcc[#]&/@Range[0,2]]
```

Comment: I see you use /@ in my case,but mine involves matrices,not function. I wrote it like you asked but the answer seems wrong to me. One more thing,if I were to put

Comment: I see you use /@ in my case,but mine involves matrices,not function. I wrote it like you asked but the answer seems wrong to me. One more thing,if I were to put 1/Sqrt[9] Sum[(w^cc[i] MatrixPower[matX, i].MatrixPower[matZ, j]), 
                            {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}],it gives me the the power of w along with [i] so I know which power of matX is used but how do I put [j] beside cc along with[i]?I tried w^cc[i][j] but it didn't work.